# Continuum random variable distribution: integral and trapezium-rule methods give different result

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference

> Suppose p.d.f. is $\frac{1}{63}x^{2}$. Find the $P(4<x<5)$.

I've tried with integration method and trapezium-rule, but they give me different result.

With integration,

> $$\int_{4}^{5}\frac{1}{63}x^{2}\:dx=\left.\frac{1}{63}\:\right[_4^5\:\frac{1}{3}x^{3}=\frac{1}{63}\:(\frac{125}{3}-\frac{64}{3})=\frac{61}{189}$$

But with trapezium-rule,

> $$(5-4)\cdot\frac{f(5)+f(4)}{2}=1\cdot\frac{(\frac{25}{63}+\frac{16}{63})}{2}=\frac{41}{126}$$

What I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trapezoidal rule is an approximation.  It only gives you the same answer when you partition the interval up into $n$ pieces and take $n\to\infty$ (the limit).  Your first solution looks correct.

Comment: I don't know, but when I tried the two methods to similar problems, they give same answers. Should I just use the first method?

Comment: @Ridho, if the function is linear, the trapezoidal method will give you the exact result with a single interval.  This case it is not linear.  Generally, if you are able to find an anti-derivative, then the first method is better.  You use an approximation (like the trapezoidal rule) when you cannot get an "exact" result using some other method.

Comment: That's make sense! Thank you for helping me!